# Building rsp pages since update not working

Tags: dart, rikulo

Since updating to stream 0.70+1 whenever I try to build any rsp file I'm getting the errors listed below.

```
FileSystemEntity._throwIfError (dart:io:1637:7)
FileSystemEntity.identicalSync (dart:io:1627:18)
compileFile (package:stream/src/rspc/build.dart:36:37)
build.<anonymous closure> (package:stream/src/rspc/build.dart:126:20)
_StreamSubscriptionImpl._sendData (dart:async:1586:12)
_StreamImpl._sendData.<anonymous closure> (dart:async:1362:29)
_SingleStreamImpl._forEachSubscriber (dart:async:1446:11)
_StreamImpl._sendData (dart:async:1360:23)
_StreamImpl._add (dart:async:1162:16)
StreamController.add (dart:async:1077:35)
_Directory.list.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:609:40)
_ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:81:92)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug. Please follow [Issue 25](https://github.com/rikulo/stream/issues/25)

Comment: It shall be fixed in 0.7.0+2.